# Editing PostGIS/GeoServer data via web?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, javascript, editing, web-gis

I've got PostGIS installed and would like to create a web application to do some simple edits:

- Draw manually (over a Basemap) points, lines and polylines, using snapping 
  points (points, end of lines, intersections, center of circles)
- Delete points, lines and polylines
- Rotate a line or group of lines around a point
- Move a line or group of lines with a base point
- Move polylines and points (manually and to a point given by the coordinates)
- Edit position of vertices of polylines and lines (manually and to a point given by the coordinates)
- Create buffers around points, lines and polylines

Which is the best way to do this via web? Is there any already-built JavaScript library?

Answer (score 7):

You should use Geoserver WFS-T,WPS protocols and some client software like openlayers
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wps.html

Answer (score 4):

I would look into [Cartaro](http://cartaro.org/), it appears to be based off of [OpenLayers Editor](http://ole.geops.de/#features) by [geOps](http://www.geops.de/).

I also just saw this [OpenLayers WFS-T Using a GeoServer Hosted PostGIS Layer](http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html).

Comment: Cartaro is a combination of CMS and spatial data editing and probably not well suited for doing only spatial data editing. OpenLayers Editor however would be a good starting point. By the way I've recently added WFS-T and rotation support. Thanks for recommending our work.

Comment: How does Cartaro compare to OpenGeo Suite?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there are any "ready-to-use" libraries that covers all your needs, but with the mentioned combination of Geoserver (with wfs-t) and OpenLayers it should be possible to create what you want. Maybe mapfish has some more convenience-methods?

And, if web-based is not a "must have", then consider using Quantum GIS.